# Intellij Idea toolbars default settings

Tags: intellij-idea

Create new project. I'd like to see `Project` tab at right side of screen. Ok. I move it to right. Change width.

Now create new project. And again see `Project` at left, as default.

Can I set some "default view" for all projects?
I want use something like `perspective` in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `Window` -> `Store Current Layout as Default` does what you want. In my Case every Project use the same Android Studio Layout Settings.

Comment: Oh, yes. Solution is so simple. I do not know why, but searching them in View menu...